# Not unit-speed curve on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

This question has already been asked: [Curve on a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48357/curve-on-a-sphere)

but is slightly different because I don´t have the hypothesis that $\alpha(t)$ is a unit-speed curve; anyway I wanted to do it by myself

Prove that a curve $\alpha:I\subset \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$ whose image is on the sphere of radius $R$ has a curvature $K\ge 1/R$

My attempt:

$\alpha(t)$ verifies $x^2(t)+y^2(t)+z^2(t)=R^2$ so if we derive this twice: $$x(t)\ddot x(t) +y(t)\ddot y(t)+z(t)\ddot z(t)+ \dot x^2(t)+\dot y^2(t) + \dot z^2(t)=0$$

but we can express the left side as:

$$<\alpha(t),\ddot \alpha(t)>+ <\dot \alpha(t),\dot \alpha(t)>=0$$ which is equal to:
$$<\alpha(t),\ddot \alpha(t)>=-<\dot \alpha(t),\dot \alpha(t)>$$ then $$|<\alpha(t),\ddot \alpha(t)>|=|-<\dot \alpha(t),\dot \alpha(t)>|=|<\dot \alpha(t), \dot \alpha(t)>|=||\dot \alpha(t)||^2$$

applaying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have:

$$||\alpha(t)|| \cdot ||\ddot \alpha(t)|| \ge |<\alpha(t),\ddot \alpha(t)>|=||\dot \alpha(t)||^2$$
 hence :
$${{||\alpha(t)|| \cdot ||\ddot \alpha(t)||}\over {||\dot \alpha(t)||^2} }\ge 1$$
$${{||\ddot \alpha(t)||}\over {||\dot \alpha(t)||^2} }\ge {1\over {||\alpha(t)||}}$$

Multiplying and dividing by $||\dot \alpha(t)||$ on the left side of the inequality:

$${{||\dot \alpha(t)|| \cdot ||\ddot \alpha(t)||}\over {||\dot \alpha(t)||^3} }\ge {1\over {R}}$$
because $R=||\alpha(t)||$

I think I´m almost done, I want to have in the left side of the inequality the expression :$${||\dot \alpha(t) x \ddot \alpha(t)||}\over {||\dot \alpha(t)||^3}$$ which is the curvature $K$ of $\alpha(t)$ maybe I can use that fact that $$||\dot \alpha(t) x \ddot \alpha(t)||=||\dot \alpha(t)||\cdot ||\ddot \alpha(t)|| sin\theta$$ but I´m not sure

I could really appreciate if you can help me in the last step :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the fact any regular curve can be reparametrized by arclength to have unit speed and reparametrization won't change the curvature of the curve because the definition of curvature of a non-unit speed curve is just the curvature of the curve when it's parametrized by arclength.